# Can anyone identify the uniforms in these pics, dated 1903 - 1904, Calcutta?

Tags: military, india, germany, uniform

A little background... his father was a merchant with offices in Bremen and Calcutta; his mother tutored the children of the Viceroy of India. In later documents he states he was a member of the Royal Guard.

[image][image]

Comment: Higher resolution photos would be helpful. It’s often a detail like a mark on a button that tells the tale.

Comment: As for the first picture: it looks like a mensur suit.  The cap and its angle and the sword look like he's a member of a "fencing club" in the sense of the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_fencing

Comment: As for "the Emperor of India".  Hunh?  As far as I know there was no "Emperor of India" in the 19th century.

Comment: The [Emperor of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_of_India) in 1903 would be the English monarch Edward VII, before him Queen Victoria. If his mother tutored [Edward's children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandchildren_of_Queen_Victoria_and_Prince_Albert_of_Saxe-Coburg_and_Gotha#Edward_VII) there should be records. If we could see these documents that would help.

Comment: You tagged this Germany. What Emperor are we talking about?

Comment: @Schwern If the mother did the tutoring before her son was born, and if the pictures were taken in 1903, it would not have been Edward VII.

Comment: @kimchi lover  - Saying there was no Emperor of India in the 19th century is like saying there was no King of Croatia in 1900, no King of Sardinia in 1520, no King of Ireland in 1630, No King of Navarre in 1600, etc., etc.

Comment: Sorry, his mother was tutor to the Viceroy's children (der kinder des Vizekönigs) not the Emperor's children, who, incidentally, I believe would have been otherwise known as the British Raj. I tagged Germany because he was German, born in Bremen. "Mensur" makes sense to me. Although I am uncertain if he was educated in Germany or Switzerland. The uniform to the right above I assumed was possibly German colonial although he himself stated that he served with the emperor's Royal Guard.

Comment: @DanaF.DavisJr. Please update the question itself with this information.

Comment: On reflection, I think  picture 1 might be an ordinary fencing outfit and not a "mensur" one in particular.  Most of the mensur images show a kind of armor apron instead of the ordinary-looking fencing jacket.

Comment: Might that have been the German Kaiser's Royal Guard?

Comment: Was not aware Kaiser Wilhelm had a Royal Guard but, I suppose it's possible, they were buddy-buddy.